How do you Replace all RS line breaks in Notepad++ with /n
I am trying to create a /n line break in notepad++ to replace the RS line break to make an actual /n line break to see the code on multiple lines.  Is there an ASCII code or something like that to enter in the Find and Replace all section? 
Picture of RS Line Break example

What is an RS line break?

I put a link to the picture on the post it's a coded line break

Please post your data as text, not image.

RS is the Record Separator character, and has ASCII code 30 (1e in hexadecimal notation). To type it on a Windows OS, hold down the Alt key and type 0 3 0 on the NumPad.
Similarly, FS is the File Separator character, with ASCII code 28 (1c in hecadecimal). See ASCII - Wikipedia for a list of ASCII control codes.
In the Find/Replace box, you can type those characters with escape code \x1e (for RS) and \x1c (for FS). Mark the "Extended" option in the Find/Replace dialog. In the Replace input, type whatever you want to replace with, like \n for a line break.

Any feedback, @MattDolly?
